Azure Container Apps with static egress IP causes internal dns resolution not to work
I'm using Azure Container Apps to build an application.
When I configure a static outbound IP address using a NatGW for my container apps environment, then the dns resolution for communication between containers no longer is working.
I have several container apps that are communicating with each other via HTTP. Previously I was using a Container Apps Environment that is on a private virtual network but without a NAT Gateway. I could communicate between the container apps by using the (automatically generated) private container url. IE: https://[mycontainer].[envname].westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io. This container environment was on Consumption mode (not workload profiles).
But now I have the requirement that I need to use a static IP address for egress traffic. So I deployed a new Container Apps Environment to a subnet that uses a NATGW and a Public IP Address. I also needed to configure Workload Profiles (Consumption) for this to work.
But now I have the problem that the communication between Container Apps is no longer working. They cannot resolve the generated urls (https://[mycontainer].[envname].westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io)
I can communicate between the apps if I send my own Host header, but that shouldn't be the case.
There's a difference if I do an nslookup command from inside the container.
New env (with NATGw and without workload profiles)
nslookup mycontainer.myenv.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

** server can't find mycontainer.myenv.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io: NXDOMAIN

Old env (without natgw and without workload profiles)
nslookup myapp.myenv.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
;; Got recursion not available from 9.0.0.2
;; Got recursion not available from 9.0.0.2
;; Got recursion not available from 9.0.0.2
;; Got recursion not available from 9.0.0.2
Server:         9.0.0.2
Address:        9.0.0.2#53

Name:   myapp.myenv.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
Address: 9.0.12.173
;; Got recursion not available from 9.0.0.2

I've already tried to configure a private DNS zone but that also doesn't seem to be picked up. Do I need to configure a route table with custom routes?
Thanks for your help!
Here's the pulumi code we use to set up the environment:
        var infraSubnet = new Network.Subnet(infraSubnetName, new Network.SubnetArgs()
        {
            ResourceGroupName = MyResourceGroup.Name,
            VirtualNetworkName = MyVirtualNetwork.Name,
            AddressPrefix = MyNaming.SubnetRanges.ContainerAppEnvSubnetRange,
            NatGateway = new SubResourceArgs()
            {
                Id = MyNATGateway.Id
            },
            Delegations = new[]
            {
                // We need these delegations so we can
                new Network.Inputs.DelegationArgs()
                {
                    Name = "Microsoft.App/environments",
                    ServiceName = "Microsoft.App/environments"
                }
            },
        });


        var appManagedEnvironment = new App.ManagedEnvironment(MyContainerAppManagedEnvironmentName, new App.ManagedEnvironmentArgs()
        {
            ResourceGroupName = MyResourceGroup.Name,
            EnvironmentName = MyContainerAppManagedEnvironmentName,
            Location = ResourceGroup.Location,
            WorkloadProfiles = [
                new WorkloadProfileArgs
                {
                    Name = "Consumption",
                    WorkloadProfileType = "Consumption"
                }
            ],
            VnetConfiguration = new App.Inputs.VnetConfigurationArgs()
            {

                InfrastructureSubnetId = infraSubnet.Id,

                Internal = true,
            },
            ZoneRedundant = true,
        });


Small Update.. if I configure a private DNS zone which points to the CAE ip address then it does work, but then the traffic exists the cluster.

Another interesting find.. the file /etc/resolv.conf is different between the two environments. The newer environment doesn't specify ndots:5.
But I can't seem to find how to specify the number of ndots. In Kubernetes, apparently you can set this, but no idea how to do this in Azure Container Apps.

are you using the out of the box azure dns servers ?

I'm using Azure private zones.. but it's my understanding that I shouldn't have to use private dns zones, because kubernetes (what container apps is built on) should already handle the internal dns.

Sorry I mean in your VNET, do you have some custom DNS servers / route table etc ?

Originally, I setup the container apps environment in a new vnet with only the nat gw there. So no dns servers, route tables, etc. Then I could not communicate between apps.
Then, when I setup a private dns zone and associated it with the vnet and then create A Records for each container app, I could communicate between apps, but then the traffic leaves the container apps environment. That seems like it's not the right way moving forward. Afaik, kubernetes should have an internal dns that handles routing between apps.

That should work tbh. could you share your infra as code?

I'll add the infra as code to the question

I have just (for azure support), created a minimal repro:

Create Vnet (erwin-test)
Create Natgw with public ip and associate it with default snet of vnet
create a container apps environment with two 'getting started' container apps in them (erwin-test-app1 and erwin-test-app2)
connect using terminal to app 1.
perform curl to app 2 using url provided. in my case: https://erwin-test-app2.happypond-7c053376.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io
observe not working

